# Drupal 6 Redirect automatically when selecting deepest item from a hierarchycal tree

Tags: php, drupal-6

Drupal 6, Redirect automatically when selecting deepest item from a hierarchycal tree, like:

Tree Parent
   .|_Child 1
   ....|__Child 1.1
   .|_Child 2

Redirect action must occour only on the last items: Child 1.1 and Child 2
Destination of creat different content types, will be defined in js array. 
But how to send hierarchical select value to, destination add content type? 
Maybe like redirect_url?tid_value=value123.
I have to save all taxonomy path, but it would be enouth to get deepest one tid value.
Should i use multipage approuch here?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question:

create new module, like 'enter_content'.

In this module i am loading javascript file, which binds ...bind('change-hierarchical-select', ... with custom js function, to all hierarchical select field elements.

When happens On change event, js checks for element class ...hasClass('has-no-children').

So when there is no childrens i am doing redirect to my desired create content type form.